# Re-queue rabbit AMQP messages at the tail of the queue after max attempts

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm currently using RabbitMQ with spring (spring-rabbit-1.2.0-RELEASE), with the configuration below :

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
<!-- Asynchronous exchanges -->
<!-- Admin -->
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<!-- Error Handler -->
<bean id="biErrorHandler" class="my.project.sync.BiErrorHandler" />
<!-- Message converter -->
<bean id="biMessageConverter" class="my.project.sync.BiMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="retryInterceptor" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"/>
    <property name="retryOperations" ref="retryTemplate" />
    <property name="messageKeyGenerator" ref="biKeyGenerator" />
</bean> 

<bean id="biKeyGenerator" class="my.project.sync.BiMessageKeyGenerator"/>
<bean id="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"/>

<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="3000" />
            <property name="maxInterval" value="30000" />
        </bean>     
    </property>
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
        </bean>     
    </property>
</bean>  

 <rabbit:queue id="biSynchronizationQueue" name="BI_SYNCHRONIZATION_QUEUE" durable="true" />
<rabbit:listener-container message-converter="biMessageConverter" concurrency="1" 
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    error-handler="biErrorHandler"
    advice-chain="retryInterceptor"
    acknowledge="auto">
    <rabbit:listener queues="BI_SYNCHRONIZATION_QUEUE" ref="biSynchronizationService" method="handleMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

I would like to requeue the message at the tail of the queue after the third attempt. But i don't find a way to perform that.

Is someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer`, use a custom `MessageRecoverer` that uses a `RabbitTemplate` to send the message to the back of the queue; then throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` so the message will be rejected.

You could subclass the `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer`, send the message in `recover()` and then call `super.recover()` (which simply throws the exception). Or just do all the implementation in your own `recover()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary I will try it tomorrow and report back !

Comment: FYI, we added a `RepublishMessageRecoverer` to the upcoming 1.3 release; see the last paragraph here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#async-listeners

Comment: @GaryRussell What do you see as the main benefits of RepublishMessageRecoverer over using a dead letter exchange?

Comment: Not much difference, really, just an alternative. However, there are a few things: 1. The republished message gets `x-exception-stacktrace` and `x-exception-message` headers. 2. You can route to different exchanges/routing keys based on message content (although that would need a little custom coding - subclass the `RabbitTemplate` and override `send(exchange, key, message)`). 3. You can further modify the message (using the same technique). 4. ... . With the `DLE` the message gets forwarded with some rabbit-specific info in the headers, but no application-level info relating to the failure.

Comment: Great example... but how could I set this up using annotations and on latest version, where recoverer is expected to be a `MethodInvocationRecoverer<?>` ? 

This old definition I found written a year ago by @GaryRussell is no longer valid :( 

`.recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())`

Comment: I suggest you start a new question for this - include your code.

Answer (score 3):

I used this tip, but then went a slightly different direction by using a deadletter queue.  For me, it was more explicit than putting the message at the end of the queue.

```
 <rabbit:queue name="content.variantchange.queue" durable="true" queue-arguments="queueArguments"/>

<util:map id="queueArguments">
    <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="content.deadletter.topic"/>
</util:map>

  <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="content.deadletter.topic">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="content.deadletter.queue"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>

<rabbit:queue name="content.deadletter.queue" durable="true"/>
```

Once you have the dead letter queue in place, you can do whatever you want via another consumer (including adding it back to the original queue.)

I also ended up using the stateless version of the interceptor Gary recommended which allowed me to not have to worry about a message id generator.

```
<bean id="retryInterceptor" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"/>
    <property name="retryOperations" ref="retryTemplate" />
</bean>
```